# change different words in text with javascript

Tags: jquery, function, words

I have a text and I would like to be able to create a small jquery / javascript function to change different words in this text depending on the  attributes surrounding the word that I would like to change.

I have something wrong here but I can't tell what at this point.
Here is what it looks like:

https://jsfiddle.net/massiace/mq0cvn25/10/

My text:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Today I feel so <span id="1" class="change" w1="sad" w2="grumpy">happy</span> but 
I don't know exactly what to <span id="2" class="change" w1="eat" w2="like" w3="feel">do</span>.
```

So I tried to create a each function to iterate all "change" classes and to store each words (let say I can have a max of 10 words) in the words variable. Any help would be a real blessing!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".change" ).each(function( index, obj ) {
    countId = 0;
    words = [];
    for(i=1 ; i>10 ; i++){
        if($(this).attr("w" + i)){
          words[i] = $(this).attr("w" + i);
        }
      };
    count = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      count++;
      $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).text(words[count % words.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/massiace/mq0cvn25/10/

Comment: how do you want to control which word (from which attribute) should be actually set as inner text of each <span>?

Comment: Does this depend on user interaction? I saw no event...?

Comment: Hi zer00ne, there is no event but that could be a good idea to trig the change of words with mouse activity or even scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a lot of typos in your code. Tidy up and keep your code clean and you will discover many problems yourself.

Read my inlined comments below.

1. Use `var` when you define new variables.
2. [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is how you add (append) new elements to an array.
3. `this` in JavaScript is tricky. [Learn to use it correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".change").each(function(index, obj) {
    // Cache the current element.
    var $this = $(this);

    // Use "var" to define variables.
    var words = [];
    var count = 0;
    var attr;

    // First issue: "i>10" that you have makes it an infinite loop.
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      attr = $this.attr("w" + i);
      if (attr) {
        // Use push to add a new element to an array.
        words.push(attr);
      } else {
        // No more attributes on this element, break the loop.
        break;
      }
    };

    setInterval(function() {
      count++;

      // The "this" keyword inside this anonymous function is not the same "this" as above.
      // Now you benefit from having the current element stored in "$this".
      $this.fadeOut(400, function() {
        $this.text(words[count % words.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Today I feel so <span id="1" class="change" w1="sad" w2="grumpy">happy</span> but I don't know exactly what to <span id="2" class="change" w1="eat" w2="like">do</span>.
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's so clever! I still have few things to learn. Thanks for your time to correct me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be ok for you but I replaced w1 w2... attributes for one data-words attribute with words separated by comma. It's easy to parse them into array with String.prorotype.split() method. Code seem to be more elegant for me now. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.change').each(function(){
    slideWords($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});

function slideWords(getSpanId){
  var span = $("#"+getSpanId);
  var words = $(span).attr('data-words').split(',');

  repeat(0);
  function repeat(iter){
    $(span).text(words[iter]).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).fadeOut(400, function(){
      var next = !words[iter+1] ? 0:iter+1;
      repeat(next);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Today I feel so <span id="1" class="change" data-words="sad,grumpy,good,excited"></span> but I don't know exactly what to <span id="2" class="change" data-words="eat,like,do"></span>.
```

Comment: Wow I'm impressed, it looks really nice like that!